# Cauchy integral theorem, of $e^z /( z-1)$?

Tags: complex-analysis, integration

So I'm doing some problems on Cauchy Integral theorem, and one of the questions is to find this integral about the circle $|z| = 2$

of $\exp(z)/(z-1)$

I don't think it's possible because it's not an analytic function, but I don't think I'm right...or am I?

thank you!

Comment: $\exp$ is an analytic function, that's what you need to use Cauchy's Integral formula (not the theorem) : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_integral_formula

Comment: thanks for the edit learner, I wasn't familiar with the formatting and I tried to use latex but didn't work

Comment: Or you can parametrize the curve around $C_2$

Comment: So do I just use the formula with a=1 and f(z)=exp(z)?

Comment: Ah, I thought of a different point of confusion, but I think giranshiido nailed it on the nose.

Comment: ok I did it and got 2*pi*i*e
thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$$e^z\;\;\text{is an entire function}$$

$$\text{By CIT, for an analytic function in}\;\{z\in\Bbb C\;;\;|z|\le 2\}\;,\;\;\frac1{2\pi i}\int\limits_{|z|=2}\frac{f(z)}{z-1}dz=f(1)$$

Comment: Yeah , I tried this and got 2*pi*i*e, hopefully that's right. Thank you :D

Comment: No, it is not right. Read carefully.

Comment: The answer is *not* $2 \pi i \cdot f(1) = 2 \pi i \cdot e^1$ ?

Comment: @TheChaz2.0 , dude: you're asking about oooooold stuff! Perhaps there was a misunderstanding here: I can't remember. The answer **to his question** indeed is $\;2\pi if(1)=2\pi ie\;$, but the answer *of what I wrote* is simply $\;f(1)\;$ as I already divided by $\;2\pi i\;$...perhaps that's what was meant, I'm not sure.

Comment: Sorry for all the necro-posting. I am trying to do my due diligence before asking a question(s) in the coming hours. Let's just say that complex analysis is harder for me than real analysis and algebra ever were... : /